# Firebase Cloud Messaging and Notification error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

i was trying firebase cloud messaging with the QuickStart app provided by firebase, i copied code from QuickStart app to my app, it builds well, but when i send message from firebase it gives this error please help:

```
04-20 15:58:01.434 7967-8510/com.example.akshaymanagooli.firebasenotify E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
  Process: com.example.akshaymanagooli.firebasenotify, PID: 7967
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/com.example.akshaymanagooli.firebasenotify-2/base.apk:classes2.dex)
      at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzbj(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzc(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzi(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzJ(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Make sure you add both MyFirebaseMessagingService & MyFirebaseInstanceIDService in manifest file

Comment: ya i have added both

Comment: do you add - google-services.json file in root of your application

Comment: Did you declare classpath at root level?

Comment: @user5594218 if he didn't add google-services.json file then he can't compile the project and can't run it.So, that is not the problem.

Comment: yes andy i have added this one right: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: Which version dependency you are using for firebase-messaging

Comment: ya i am using 10.2.1

Comment: Try with this version 9.2.1.

Comment: What are other dependencies you are using please share your denpendencies.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

Comment: did you add this line? apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: ya i have added that line

Comment: Okey try with 9.2.1 version for messaging and core. Make sure both have same version.

Comment: hey i got it with 10.2.1, but i am getting notification only when app is in background

Comment: Make sure you have this permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: hey i checked in log, i am getting message but no notification when app is on\

Comment: Try to check in your phone if you not blocked the notification for the application.Many new devices have this kind of facility to block the notification.

Comment: no i am getting notifications but only when app is in background, if app is in foreground i will get the message which i check in log, but it wont show any notification